# Regular expression to extract only values ​of a specific pattern within parentheses

Tags: regex

`aaa[image,L,0]bbb  [1]ddddffffdddd[image,R,0]ccc`

When there is a String of this type, I used the following regular expression to extract only the value of the form `[image,L,0]`.

`\[.*?[^\]]\,[LMR]\,.*?[^\[]\]`

In the above String, I wanted the result to be `[image,L,0]`,`[image,R,0]`.
However, the actual extracted values ​​were `[image,L,0]`,`[1]ddddffffdddd[image,R,0]`.
I want to extract only the values ​​with two `,` in square brackets. I want to know what am I missing in my regex.

Comment: The dot will skip over any closing `]`. You can get these by using [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): [`\[[^\]\[]*\,[LMR]\,[^\[\]]*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/nSpJel/1)

Comment: Welcome! If there can occur more than two commas inside the square brackets and you only want those with two at most, you need to [add them to the negated class too](https://regex101.com/r/YSkCvB/1).

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/rfxaKS/1) will work.